# Is there a way to get markdown code interaction in Visual Studio Code's integrate jupyter notebook functionality?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, lint

For example, getting text highlights and rules suggestions like one does when editing a .md file, but in the markdown blocks of a Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer on this extension. Currently we have some limitations in our notebook functionality as we have implemented notebooks as a separate webview (so we don't have easy access to base VS Code editing features for markdown files). So no markdown highlighting currently. If you want to upvote here, we have had other customers request this issue here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4356